# How to delete a class, if scrollTop == 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to delete a class, if scrollTop == 0?

Now when you scroll down the page, the navbar works as it should.

But when I scroll the page to the top itself - the class is not deleted. Tell me how to do in this situation.

My code

```js
var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
var body = document.querySelector('body');

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > scrollTop) {
    navbar.classList.add('slideUp');

    body.classList.remove('styling');
    navbar.classList.remove('styling');
  } else if (window.pageYOffset < scrollTop) {
    body.classList.add('styling');
    navbar.classList.add('styling');
    navbar.classList.remove('slideUp');
  }

  scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding-top: 80px;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00f;
  height: 80px;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.navbar.styling {
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar.slideUp {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
```

Thank. I will be glad to any help

Comment: which class you want to remove?

Comment: @brk - class .styling

Comment: Let's make it sure, you want to remove a class from the element's class list instead of deleting a class from the CSS ..?

Comment: @Teemu - now after scrolling down the page, then return to its original state - class .stiling is not deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check `scrollTop` after its value has been updated from `window.pageYOffset`:

```js
var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
var body = document.querySelector('body');

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > scrollTop) {
    navbar.classList.add('slideUp');

    body.classList.remove('styling');
    navbar.classList.remove('styling');
  } else if (window.pageYOffset < scrollTop) {
    body.classList.add('styling');
    navbar.classList.add('styling');
    navbar.classList.remove('slideUp');
  }

  scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

  // Here
  if (scrollTop === 0) {
    body.classList.remove('styling');
    navbar.classList.remove('styling');
  }
  
  console.log(`for scrollTop = ${scrollTop}, classes are:`, navbar.classList.value);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding-top: 80px;
  min-height: 2000px;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00f;
  height: 80px;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.navbar.styling {
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar.slideUp {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
```